# how to add data to enum in c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, enums

OK so I have a list which contains few string data set,
i want to assign this list values to enum according ling 
my code below

```
 namespace ILS.VM.Config
{
    public class loadPortDetails
    {
        public void Ports()
        {

            List<string> portnameLIST= new List<string>();
            portnameLIST.add(31);
            portnameLIST.add(25);
            portnameLIST.add(66);   


              //BaudRate.Baud_11001 = ;
        }               

    }

    public enum BaudRate
    {
        Baud_FLOOR1,
         Baud_FLOOR2,
        Baud_FLOOR3,
        Baud_NONE = 0
    };

}
```

data in the list has to be given as a values to the enum

for example:

```
Baud_FLOOR1=should have the values from portlist (portnamelist[1])
```

Baud_FLOOR2=should have the values from portlist (portnamelist[2])

Comment: I think you need to use `Dictionary`

Answer (score 6):

You can't add/change the [`enum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx) value in runtime

If you need a key-value pairs, I suggest to use [`Dictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Update:**

So if you need to store `int FloorNumber` -> `string PortNumber` relationship 
you should create a dictionary

```
 Dictionary<int, string> floorPortMap = new Dictionary<int, string>();
```

To add pair you should use [`Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7z0zy8k(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

```
floorPortMap.Add(10, "777"); // adds the (10, "777") pair to the dictionary.
```

To update pair you should use `[]` operator like

```
floorPortMap[10] = "8888" // changes previous (10, "777") pair to (10, "888")
```

Comment: can you show me an example as Enum is outside the class!, how to add data from the class List to enum using dictionary ?

Comment: @AnilGadiyar You need to store `floor_number` - `port_name`, don't you?

Comment: YES!  you are corrrect

Answer (score 1):

Note that unless the value is specifically assigned the first enum will have the value 0, so in your code both Baud_FLOOR1 and Baud_NONE would have the value 0.

If the values will not change at runtime - you can assign values like this :

```
public enum BaudRate
{
  Baud_NONE,     // assignment of zero to first enum not required
  Baud_FLOOR1 = 31,
  Baud_FLOOR2 = 25,
  Baud_FLOOR3 = 66
};
```

Comment: Enum is outside the class!, how to add data from the class List to enum using dictionary ?